# Why do I get a light halo only on sunny exposures using my FED 2?

Tags: exposure, troubleshooting, film, old-cameras, rangefinder

I recently bought a FED 2 and I got some weird results from my test roll. I've been taking pics in various conditions (inside and outside) and I do get a light halo on sunny outside pics (see below on the top right and left corner). Halo that I don't get (or I don't see) when it's darker.

I checked the lens and it seems alright. It's clearly been used but it's not damaged. I'm just wondering if another piece of the camera can be responsible of that.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a simple light leak. Could be damage to the shutter curtain. That's pretty common on old cameras. Does anything affect this? Like, if you snap and then don't wind for a while, does that frame get really washed out? This site isn't really the best for troubleshooting this kind of thing.

Comment: See: http://www.dyxum.com/dforum/old-film-cameras-and-light-leaks-article_topic102258.html  looks like that article's example of perforation in the shutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely looks like a damaged shutter blind-this can happen if you don't use a lens cap on sunny days the sun will burn the blind via the lens